# how to merge and sum frames of images into one in Digital Micrograph?

Tags: dm-script

I tried to use the merge function to sum it together, but the intensity of the Merge Image does not equal to the addition of the two original images. Does anyone know how to do it in DM?

Comment: Can you give an example what you did and what exactly you need? If you have two images of same size, one with the label 'A' and one with 'B' you can simply write ZZ = A + B, but I guess that is not the answer you seek, or is it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question as asked is maybe a bit under-specified. For simple "intensity adding" of two images of the same size ( pixel dimensions ) you can simply use the label letters and a simple equation like f.e.:

[image: Starting situation]

will give you:

[image: Added intensities]

I also don't know what the 'merge' function you refer to should be. What script command are you referring to?